# After Showing Alert box subview button is automatically hidden in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing search func for table view list. Everything working fine, but after no search data found I am showing alert box. But after I call alert box search button automatically hidden. here my code-

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     month_names()
    search_params = ["International","National","State"]
    search_btn.hidden = true
    search_btn.enabled = false

    self.typePickerView.hidden = true
    self.typePickerView.dataSource = self
    self.typePickerView.delegate = self

    //other pickerView code like dataSource and delegate
    self.view.addSubview(typePickerView)
    self.view.superview?.addSubview(search_btn)
     }
```

after data load from server  I did this-

```
    search_btn.hidden = false
    search_btn.enabled = true
    self.view.superview?.addSubview(search_btn)
```

but when no search data found I call fun to show alert box, after this **search_btn** is automatically hidden

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if(shouldShowSearchResults){
        if(Search_data.count > 0){
           return Search_data.count
        }
        else{
            shouldShowSearchResults = false
            set_no_data()
           return TableData.count
        }
    }
    else{
        return TableData.count
    }


}
```

and

```
    func set_no_data(){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.show_alert_view("No Results Found!")
        self.search_btn.hidden = false
        self.search_btn.enabled = true
        self.view.superview?.addSubview(self.search_btn)
    })
}
```

and my alert box code look like-

```
       func  show_alert_view(message:String)  {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:
        message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:   UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:  nil)
}
```

Please give solution for this, Thank you in advance...

Comment: update screenshot accordingly

Comment: hide this `self.view.superview?.addSubview(self.search_btn)` in inside the `func set_no_data(){` function and try once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I got answer!
Replace code-

```
self.view.superview?.addSubview(search_btn) with
self.view.addSubview(self.search_btn)
```